# Outlining specific parts of array

Tags: tables, arrays, columns

I couldn't find this anywhere else. I have an array with a bunch of numbers in it, and I am very new to posting on this forum.

This is from a template that I have to use for a document. Here's the code for the table. What I want is that last column to only have a box around the bottom right number. How can I do that?

```
\begin{table}[tbp]
    \[ 
    \begin{array}{c | c | c | c | c | c | }
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{ j } & \multicolumn{1}{c}1 & \multicolumn{1}{c}2 & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}4 & \multicolumn{1}{c}7 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\text{max}} \\
    \cline{2-6}
    1 & 1 & 2 & 4 & 7 & 7 \\
     \cline{2-6}
    2 & 2 & 4 & 8 & 2 & 8 \\
     \cline{2-6}
    3 & 3 & 6 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
     \cline{2-6}
    4 & 4 & 8 & 8 & 4 & 8 \\
     \cline{2-6}
    5 & 5 & 6 & 4 & 3 & 6 \\
     \cline{2-6}
    6 & 6 & 4 & 8 & 6 & 8 \\
     \cline{2-6}
    7 & 7 & 2 & 4 & 1 & 7 \\
     \cline{2-6}
    8 & 8 & 0 & 0 & 8 & 8 \\
     \cline{2-6}
    \text{min} &  &  &  &  & 7 \\
     \cline{6-6} 
\end{array}
\]
\end{table}
```

Here's the picture of whta it's generating.

[image: Table of numbers]

Comment: Hello, your sample doesn't compile. Please provide a minimal *working* example next time. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here is one possibility:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c}
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{ j } & \multicolumn{1}{c}1 & \multicolumn{1}{c}2 & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}4 & \multicolumn{1}{c}7 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\text{max}} \\
    \cline{2-5}
    1 & 1 & 2 & 4 & 7 & 7 \\
     \cline{2-5}
    2 & 2 & 4 & 8 & 2 & 8 \\
     \cline{2-5}
    3 & 3 & 6 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
     \cline{2-5}
    4 & 4 & 8 & 8 & 4 & 8 \\
     \cline{2-5}
    5 & 5 & 6 & 4 & 3 & 6 \\
     \cline{2-5}
    6 & 6 & 4 & 8 & 6 & 8 \\
     \cline{2-5}
    7 & 7 & 2 & 4 & 1 & 7 \\
     \cline{2-5}
    8 & 8 & 0 & 0 & 8 & 8 \\
     \cline{2-6}
    \text{min} &  &  &  &  & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{7} \\
     \cline{6-6}
  \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Is it like the following?

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}

\begin{document}

\[ 
\begin{array}{c | c | c | c | c | c }
\multicolumn{1}{c}{j} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{4} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{7} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\max} \\
\cline{2-5}
1 & 1 & 2 & 4 & 7 & 7 \\
 \cline{2-5}
2 & 2 & 4 & 8 & 2 & 8 \\
 \cline{2-5}
3 & 3 & 6 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
 \cline{2-5}
4 & 4 & 8 & 8 & 4 & 8 \\
 \cline{2-5}
5 & 5 & 6 & 4 & 3 & 6 \\
 \cline{2-5}
6 & 6 & 4 & 8 & 6 & 8 \\
 \cline{2-5}
7 & 7 & 2 & 4 & 1 & 7 \\
 \cline{2-5}
8 & 8 & 0 & 0 & 8 & 8 \\
 \cline{2-6}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\min} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{7} \\
 \cline{6-6}
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]